# Include cdn hosted js files in index.html in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have tried searching for a solution everywhere, but I am not able to find a correct way to include .js files hosted in CDN into index.html in Angular 4/5. I know we can add it to angular.json but for that, I have to download it and save it. Is there a way where I can include js file. The external JS files will have generated HTML. Also if I want to include any tracking scripts, which are hosted in CDN what is the way forward?

So for example if I am including `<script src="abc.com/abc.js"></script>` in the index.html it doesn't load.

Comment: Why can't you just include them as `script`s to `index.html`?

Comment: I did try that, but its not working

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you want to add Jquery from hosted CDN. and want to access `$('#someid')` or `Jquery('.anyclass').` follow the steps.

**Step1:** 
Add in index.html

```
 <body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

**Step 2:**

Add markup in .html

```
<p id="jd"></p>
```

**Step 3**
Write the logic in .ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any; // Add any variable to access the functionality

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('#jd').text('This is value');
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, my external JS files will generate some HTML content on page load, I just have to include the external js files. I don't actually have to use it in the app. So whatever in include in <script src=''abc.com/abc.js"></script> doesn't load

Comment: Well, there is need to make some tweaks to get the job done. sorry i cant help